# Calc Embedded Mode keybindings

Tags: calc

I am trying to use calc to modify equations in an org mode buffer. Activating calc in embedded mode works, but not without opening the calc stack buffer itself. That is, `C-x * e` puts the `CalcEmbed` mode line on my org buffer, and makes the buffer unmodifiable. However, the major mode remains `Org`. I have to run `C-x * c` to open the calc stack buffer, from where I can edit the equation, and have the changes automatically reflected in my org buffer.

Based on my reading of the manual, it seems like no stack buffer should be required. To whit:

> When Embedded mode begins, Calc pushes the current formula onto the stack. No Calc stack window is created; however, Calc copies the top-of-stack position into the original buffer at all times. You can create a Calc window by hand with C-x * o if you find you need to see the entire stack.

[source](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Basic-Embedded-Mode.html#Basic-Embedded-Mode)

Am I misunderstanding? I should note that I'm using evil, so keys like `a` and `f` are shadowed by the evil bindings. If I'm not misunderstanding, how can I more or less "turn off" evil mode for the duration of the Embedded Mode session?

Comment: Looks like turning off evil mode is as easy as `C-z`, and the toggling is fast enough to be usable.

Comment: You can use C-z as others have said, but I find it more useful to use the \ binding to set evil-mode to pass through the next keystroke. When I need more than one keystroke in emacs mode, then I do C-z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `emacs -q` to bring up a clean session, then testing out the Embedded mode in a clean file, verifies that the embedding does indeed work without the stack buffer. Running `C-z` to temporarily disable evil is good enough for my use case.

Comment: (You can accept your own answer.)